# How to detect that a unit was changed?

Tags: delphi

Everytime an user is updating a particular unit (or a particular classe), I want to raise an error or show a warning. The purpose is to warn the developer to not forget to update the DUnit tests. My idea is to make a hash of the dcu (or the classe) and compare with the previous hash we had. the problem is that at run time I do not have access to the .pas so I must generate this "hash" without any access to the .pas and I don't know if it's feasible.

Comment: Is a "post build" command not what you are looking for? You can run your hashing generator after each build and trigger a warning for the developer.

Comment: If you do have access to the DCU, an alternative could be a directory monitor. These can detect  changes and react in many different ways.

Comment: @fpiette thanks yes it's a way, but I would from inside the app do this. I will look If I can not make a "hash" of the classe with the help of the RTTI

Comment: Do this from inside which app?